# How to find the index of a string pattern in a Collection within a Forloop on the Collection

Tags: c#, linq

While looping through a collection, I check for "Billing Address" pattern and then would like to read and capture all lines until the index position of "Shipping Address". 
How to find the index Position of a string_pattern in a collection when inside a for loop of the same collection.
Is there an efficient way to do this - maybe using Linq. ?
Here is an example code snip - 
Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = new string[] 
                                {
                                    "bla bla",
                                    "bla bla bla",
                                    "bla bla ...",
                                    "bla bla bla bla",
                                    "Billing Address",
                                    "Billing Address line 1",
                                    "Billing Address line 2",
                                    "Billing Address line 3",
                                    "Billing Address line 4",
                                    "Shipping Address",
                                    "Shipping Address line 1",
                                    "Shipping Address line 2",
                                    "Shipping Address line 3",
                                    "Shipping Address line 4",
                                };

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (lines[i].Contains("Billing Address"))
            {
                // Capture all the lines until the line "Shipping Address"

                // Is there a way maybe using Linq to get the index position of "Shipping Address"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can not say anythign regarding Linq. Not my area of Expertise. But if you made a Enumeration to track in wich part of the Adress/mode you are (Bla, BillingAdress, ShippingAdress), it becomes a simple switch and setting of the Enumeration variable as lines are parsed.

Comment: so what is the expected outcome?

Comment: I don't think linq is a help here. You just want to declare a int before your for that will hold the index. You assign the value when you hit the condition. Btw if you want more oo aproach start by using List<> instead of array it will help you imo.

Comment: How about the IndexOf method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using LINQ to get the index of `"Shipping Address"` within `lines`:

```
var index = Enumerable.Range(0,lines.Length)
                       .FirstOrDefault(i => lines[i] == "Shipping Address");
```

Or you could use `Array.IndexOf` like @MongZhu suggested in the comments:

```
var index = Array.IndexOf(lines, "Shipping Address");
```

You can capture all the elements in `lines` that contain `"Billing Address"` with:

```
var billingLines = lines.Where(x => x.Contains("Billing Address")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your collection using linq:

```
var result = lines.Where(s => s.StartsWith("Billing Address"));
```

Or if you prefer using Contains:

```
var result = lines.Where(s => s.Contains("Billing Address"));
```

Comment: How is this supposed to get the index?